# exclude target/classes from maven's runtime classpath

Tags: eclipse, maven

I created a new maven project in Eclipse with default architecture. I want to execute a rhino javascript when I build with a specific profile. My project has the following facets : Dynamic Web Project 2.5, Java and Javascript. I have no class, only static web files.

When I try to compile the following profile, using the Maven runtime classpath, I receive an error that says:

```
Unable to access jarfile C:\Users\Francis\workspace\bulle\target\classes;C:\Users
\Francis\.m2\repository\rhino\js\1.7R2\js-1.7R2.jar.
```

Why is it trying to open target/classes? How can I exclude this from maven's classpath?

```xml
<plugin>
  <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
  <artifactId>maven-antrun-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>1.7</version>
  <executions>
    <execution>
      <phase>compile</phase>
      <configuration>
        <target>
          <property name="runtime_classpath" refid="maven.compile.classpath" />
          <java jar="${runtime_classpath}" 
              classpath="org.mozilla.javascript.tools.shell.Main"
              fork="true" failonerror="true">
            <arg value="src/main/script/concat-all.js" />
          </java>
        </target>
      </configuration>
      <goals>
        <goal>run</goal>
      </goals>
    </execution>
  </executions>
</plugin>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`${runtime_classpath}` is going to interpolate the entire "runtime" classpath string used by Maven, not a single JAR file.

Try

```
      <java classpath="${runtime_classpath}" 
          classname="org.mozilla.javascript.tools.shell.Main"
          fork="true" failonerror="true">
        <arg value="src/main/script/concat-all.js" />
      </java>
```

See [Ant Java Task documentation](https://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/java.html)